# while true цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне создать условие

```
    with open('ip.txt', 'r') as f:
        ips = f.readlines()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1) А что такое "цикл while 1 условие не прошел"? Это "while True:"? 2) ,Что такое "2 условие он не проверял"? Какое 2?

Comment: Ответ Сергея Шашко не помог?

Comment: В решении Сергея вообще нет цикла while. Прошу прощения, но мне сложно так общаться. Я не понимаю ни про while, ни про "4 строчка" ("if response == 0:"?). Надеюсь, кто-то поймёт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ind = 0
for index, ip in enumerate(ips):
    response = subprocess.call(['ping', '-n', '2', ip], shell=True)
    if response == 0:
        label.config(text=f'pc with index {index} off')
        label.pack()
    else:
        ind += 1

if ind == len(ips):
    label.config(text=f'ALL ONLINE')
    label.pack()
```

Comment: перепесал ответ